# synchronized across classes in java

Tags: java, multithreading, class, synchronized

I have two threads running concurrently, a main thread, and a class to old a boolean variable, and I am currently having one thrad print odds and the other print evens, but I am having them wait for each other so that it prints 1 - 100 in order.

I am currently referencing a boolean object inside my NumberPrinter class, and I am using that to make a thread enter a waiting state to wait for the other. I know how to synchronize in the same class, but when I try to do it across threads it simply hangs and looks like the boolean variable is not being updated or synchronized with both threads. At least that's why I believe to be the problem

Thanks any advice is appreciated

My test class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        NumberPrinter np = new NumberPrinter();
        single ent = new single(np);// new state
        Double ont = new Double(np);// new state


        ent.start();
        ont.start();


    }

}
```

class for even

```
public class single extends Thread {

    private NumberPrinter printer;

    public single(NumberPrinter np) {
        this.printer = np;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        try {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(printer.isOdd);
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    if (printer.isOdd == true) {
                        wait();
                    }
                    System.out.println(i);
                    printer.isOdd = true;
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

class for odd

```
public class Double extends Thread {

    private NumberPrinter printer;
    public Double(NumberPrinter np) {
        this.printer = np;
    }


    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(printer.isOdd);
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    if (printer.isOdd == false) {
                        wait();
                    }
                    System.out.println(getName() + ": " + i);
                    printer.isOdd = false;
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

a class to hold the boolean variable

```
package single;

public class NumberPrinter {

    public boolean isOdd = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wait` and `notifyAll` need to be called on the same object from both threads. You also need to synchronize on that object as well. You're using the thread instance but there are two different instances. You can use the `printer` object for this, or you could create a `new Object()` and use that. `wait` should also be used within a while loop instead of an if statement.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            synchronized(printer) {
                System.out.println(printer.isOdd);
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    while (printer.isOdd == false) {
                        printer.wait();
                    }
                    System.out.println(getName() + ": " + i);
                    printer.isOdd = false;
                    printer.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it! I really Appreciate the help